# Maxima and minima of the function

Tags: optimization, fractional-part, maxima-minima

Let $f(x) = \dfrac{\sin \left([x ]\right)}{a} + \dfrac{\cos\left([x ] \right)}{a}$,  where $a>0$ and $[ \cdot ]$ denotes the fractional part of $x$. Then the set of values of $a$ for which $f$ can attain its maximum value is

a) $(0,4/π)$

b)$(4/π,∞)$

c)$(0,∞)$

d) none of these

Comment: Two questions : 1) Are you sure of your   sin{x}/a + cos {x}/a ? Isn't it sin{x/a} + cos {x/a} for example ? 2) What have you attempted ?

Comment: Yup it is the same Q as I wrote,

Comment: And I don't know how to solve

Answer (score 1):

One can write $f(x)=\dfrac{g(x)}{a}$ with $g(x):=sin([x])+cos([x]).$

The answer is visibly independent of $a$ because the maximum of $\dfrac{g(x)}{a}$ occurs for the same values of $x$ as the maximum of $g(x)$.

As one can check that $g(x)=\sqrt{2}\cos([x]-\frac{\pi}{4})$, it is a period-1 function. It is enough to study it on [0,1]. On this interval $g(x)$ coincides with $h(x):=\sqrt{2}\cos(x-\frac{\pi}{4})$ as shown on the graphics below. Therefore, the maximum value occurs for $x=\frac{\pi}{4}$.

The set of positive solutions is then $S=\{ \frac{\pi}{4}+k \ | \ k \in \mathbb{N} \}$

It does not coincide with any of the first three solutions... thus it's the fourth one.

[image]